# Relative Pronoun explanation in a German quote

Tags: subordinate-clause, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

So I've been looking at some German quotes and came across one by [Nietzsche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Nietzsche) that goes like this:

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die, die gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als die, die anders denken.

What are the "die's" in this sentence referring to? Is it "Menschen?" Also, when continuing a single main clause with several subordinate clauses, do you need to constantly carry forward the relative pronoun as shown here where "die" appears to be a relative pronoun four separate times?

Comment: Does it help you if I rewrite the sentence just a little? *Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die Leute, welche gleich denken (wie der junge Mensch) höher einzuschätzen als die Leute, welche anders denken.*

Comment: Note that at least in contemporary German, a comma is expected after the first instance of _denken_, since "_die gleich denken_" is a subordinate relative clause embedded into the matrix clause "_die_ […] _höher einzuschätzen_" (Duden reference: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/komma#D118)

Comment: The quotation may be false.

Comment: To clear up one point that's confusingly phrased in your question, some of the "die"s do refer to people (plural) in general (we know that from context, not grammar). They don't refer to the young "Mensch(en)" (singular accusative) that appears in the sentence.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The German words *der, die* and *das* are very often used as articles, but they are also very often used as pronouns (relative and personal pronouns)

Here is an example that is a little bit shorter than your sentence, but displays the word *die* in all three flavours:

> Zwei Männer werden in den Arrest gebracht. Die Polizisten sagen zum Gefängniswärter:
> **»Hier sind die, die die Diebstähle begangen haben.«**
>
> Two men are taken to the detention center. The policemen say to the jailer,
> **"Here are those who committed the thefts."**

- **hier = here**
  A local adverb that indicates where the action is going on. "Hier" and "here" mean: next to the speaker.
- **sind = are**
  Verb of the main clause.
- **1<sup>st</sup> die = those**
  Subject of the main clause. This word is a demonstrative pronoun. There is also an alternative form for it: *»jene«*
- **2<sup>nd</sup> die = who**
  This is the first word of the relative clause *»die die Diebstähle begangen haben«* which describes the subject. And since every relative clause starts with a relative pronoun, the 2<sup>nd</sup> *die* in this sentence is a relative pronoun. It can be replaced by an other relative pronoun in its plural form, like *»welche«.*
- **3<sup>rd</sup> die = the**
  This word is the plural definite article of the noun *Diebstähle* (*thefts*). The only way to replace it would be to turn the definite phrase *»the thefts«* into the indefinite phrase *»thefts«*, but then the article disappears completely in English and also in German.
- **Diebstähle = thefts**
  A noun.
- **begangen haben = committed**
  "Begangen" is the main verb of the relative clause and "haben" the auxiliary verb needed to create the German tense *Perfekt.*

Using the optional replacements, we get:

> Hier sind jene, welche die Diebstähle begangen haben.

This is clearer, but its not idiomatic. German native speakers do not like *jene* and *welche* very much. They prefer the demonstrative pronoun *die* and the relative pronoun *die* (and if the word is used as a definite article, you have no choice anyway).

You can also create examples with *der* and *das*, using the same pattern:

> Hier ist der, der der Derbheit entsagt.
> Hier ist das, das das Dasein erleichtert.
>
> Here is the one who renounces rudeness.
> Here is that which makes existence easier.

---

So, here is you sentence:

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, **die, die** gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als **die, die** anders denken.

The four *die*'s are:

- **1<sup>st</sup> and 3<sup>rd</sup> die = those**
  Two demonstrative pronouns. Both can be replaced by *»jene«*
- **2<sup>nd</sup> and 4<sup>th</sup> die = who**
  Two relative pronouns opening two relative clauses. Both can be replaced by *»welche«.*

With replacements (correct, but not idiomatic):

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, **jene, welche** gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als **jene, welche** anders denken.

In English:

> The surest way to corrupt a young person is to teach them to value **those who** think alike more highly than **those who** think differently.

Comment: To a non-native speaker, German punctuation rules don’t exactly make the quote easier to parse either – the abundance of commas especially around “… korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die, die …” is quite overwhelming. I don’t know what the asker’s linguistic background is, but to me, the following would be much easier to parse (albeit not correctly punctuated by German rules): “Der sicherste Weg einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren ist ihn zu lehren die, die gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als die, die anders denken.”

Comment: (Incidentally, shouldn’t there be a comma after the first _denken_ in the quote, even according to normal German rules? Aren’t relative clauses usually delimited by commas at both ends?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You are correct, a comma was missing. Since punctuation was not the subject of the question, I corrected both BlauKakapoW's question and my answer. If you have a questions about punctuation (like *"How can correct punctuation help to easier parse a German sentence?"*), feel free to ask it here: [Ask Question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). The comments are not appropriate for discussing this issue.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet German is much stricter than English about where to put commas. In English, you do whatever makes the sentence easiest to read. In German, you do what you're told.

Comment: @Hubert Apart from the missing comma in the quote, my comment was not meant as a question, but as an explanation of an additional factor that makes the sentence difficult to parse for a non-native speaker, in addition to the repetition of words with identical surface forms.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I disagree. I think, commas make it easier to parse a sentence. They bring structure into the mess of words ("Professoren sagen, Studenten haben es gut." vs "Professoren, sagen Studenten, haben es gut." or "Wir empfehlen, ihm zu folgen." vs "Wir empfehlen ihm, zu folgen.") (Translations: "Professors say students have it good." vs "Professors, students say, have it good." or "We recommend to follow him." vs "We recommend him to follow.")

Comment: @Hubert German rules dictate commas in some places that are very foreign to speakers of other languages (such as around non-finite clauses), where they can end up being distracting and confusing to learners. Commas are used to set off parentheticals in all European languages and relative clauses in most of them; but I’m not aware of any others that set off non-finite clauses with commas as German does. There is a reason why, to do with word order, but it still means that a learner can sometimes experience ‘comma overload’. If the sentence is already complex, this just adds to the complexity.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Commas in German help you to identify grammatical structures (because they are solely driven by them). Commas in English help you to identify where to breathe. Both are important, but from a grammatical viewpoint, breathing is not *that* important. ;)

Comment: @tofro: *»breathing is not that important«* In the context of punctuation, you are absolutely right. Unfortunately, though, it reminds me of some of the troubles that my hobby of singing in a choir entails: unfortunately, in fact, there are also many composers of some pieces of contemporary classical music who also seem to think that breathing is a luxury that should not be afforded to singers. (Players of wind instruments feel the same way).

Answer (score 3):

Let me rephrase with the real pronouns instead of their definite article shortcuts, and let's skip the relative clauses for now:

> … ihn zu lehren, **diese** höher einzuschätzen als **jene**.

Those *diese* and *jene* are alternatives. They are demonstrative pronouns, not relative pronouns. So they aren't referring to anything in the sentence. You have to derive their meaning from context. It's again humans of course. But not *junge Menschen* but other humans in general.

Let's add the relative clauses that explain both alternatives:

> … ihn zu lehren, **diese, welche** gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als **jene, welche** anders denken.

(Mind the comma after *denken*. It's missing in your transcript.)

Comment: The words *der, die, das,* when used as in this sentence, are not *»definite article shortcuts«* but absolutely *»real pronouns«.* The first *»die«* in *»Die Milch, die ich trank, war sauer.«* is a definite article, but the second has nothing article-like on it. It is an absolutely proper relative pronoun that does what any relative pronoun does, but no article can do: It introduces a relative clause. And the word *»die«* in *»Ich habe Martins Freundin getroffen. Die ist mir vielleicht ein Fürchtchen!«*  is a perfectly correct personal pronoun, also without anything resembling an article.

Comment: That's hair splitting.

Comment: I think most people (including me) wouldn't call it "hair splitting" but "grammar".

Answer (score 1):

No, the *die*s do not refer to Menschen. The *die*s before and after a comma each serve a different purpose, the first being a demonstrative pronoun, the second being a relative pronoun referring to the first. So "... die, die ..." translates to "... those who ...".

Comment: Du meinst, wenn statt "Menschen" im ersten Teil "Studenten" stünde, dann würden sich die <i>dies</i> danach nicht automatisch auf Studenten (Studenten, die) beziehen? Wenn es sich nicht auf Menschen bezieht - aus was denn sonst? Lebewesen?

Comment: Das jeweils erste *die* ist, wie ich schon geschrieben habe, ein Demonstrativpronomen. Ein Demonstrativpronomen muss sich nicht auf etwas beziehen. Es wird näher bestimmt durch den nachfolgenden Relativsatz.

Comment: Und "those" muss sich auch nicht auf etwas beziehen? Unterscheidest Du hier Satzelemente und Semantik? Ich meine, es muss sich semantisch schon auf etwas beziehen.

Comment: @userunknown Ein Demonstrativpronomen muss sich tatsächlich auf nichts beziehen (und tut es hier auch nicht). Das weiß schon ein Kleinkind, das auf irgendwas zeigt und "das" sagt. Der Zeigefinger ist hier der Relativsatz.

Comment: Ein Kleinkind zeigt auf etwas, sagt "Das!" und will sich dabei auf nichts beziehen? Wo zeigt es denn hin? Auf das Nichts?

Comment: @userunknown Letzlich bezieht sich alles in einem Satz auf irgenendetwas, sonst ist die Ausage sinnlos. Hier geht es aber um die Frage, ob sich ein Pronomen auf einen Bestandteil des Satzes bezieht. Und das muss bei einem Demonstativpronomen nicht der Fall sein.

Comment: Dass sich alles in einem Satz auf irgendwas bezieht würde ich mit vorsichtiger Einschränkung bejahen - allerdings war ich es nicht, der behauptet hat, ein Dp. müsse sich auf nichts beziehen. Aber konkret auf den vorliegenden Fall finde ich, die Interpretation liegt nahe, dass "Menschen" gemeint sein müssen - das ergibt sich aber schon stark aus dem Kontext. Müssten es "junge Menschen" sein, wenn es aus der sprachlichen Konstruktion stammte? Ich fürchte ja, aber aus dem Gelesenen würde ich das doch nicht folgern wollen, sondern es sind irgendwelche Menschen. Dem Sinn nach hast Du somit Recht. …

Comment: … aber es scheint mir doch unglücklich formuliert, denn wen oder was sonst, als Menschen, sollte Nietzsche hier vor Augen gehabt haben? Denkende Tiere? Maschinen, die er sich als denkende denkt?

Answer (score 1):

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die, die gleich denken höher einzuschätzen als die, die anders denken.

This sentence is like an onion: layers upon layers. The easiest way to deal with such sentences is to peel them apart bit for bit. First, the main sentence:

> Der sicherste Weg ist, ihn zu lehren.
> <sub>The most fool-proof way is to teach him.</sub>

The next layer is the answer to the question *the most fool-proof way - to do what?* The answer is a relative sentence:

> einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren.
> <sub>The most fool-proof way to corrupt a young person is to teach him.</sub>

Now, this begs a question: *to teach him - what?* The answer to this is another relative sentence:

> die höher einzuschätzen als die

The first "die" hier means "the [ones]" and the second one "the [others]". If you ask now who or what *the ones* and *the others* are: we will come to that.

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die höher einzuschätzen als die.
> <sub>The most fool-proof way to corrupt a young person is to teach him to hold the [ones] in higher esteem than the [others].</sub>

Finally, we need to adress who the ones and the others are. This is explained in two other relative clauses, following the respective "die":

> die, die gleich denken
> die, die anders denken

So, the first "die" are "the ones thinking the same" and the second "die" are "the ones thinking differently". In English one would always use "the ones - the others" and in German that is possible too, but not necessarily so. In German it is possible to define what is meant in a relative clause and have the respective *Demonstrativpronomen*<sup>1</sup>) - here "die", because it is *Akkusativ Plural* in the sentence higher up in the hierarchy stand in for the rest of the clause. For instance:

> Das, was man nicht selbst produzieren kann, muß man kaufen.
> <sub>[That] what one can't produce himself, one has to buy. - One has to buy what he cannot produce himself.</sub>

The main sentence is "Das muß man kaufen." (*One has to buy that.*) and what "Das/That" exactly constitutes is explained in the clause following the *Demonstrativpronomen*: "was man nicht selbst produzieren kann".

Now, here is the whole sentence again:

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die, die gleich denken höher einzuschätzen als die, die anders denken.
> <sub>The most fool-proof way to corrupt a young person is to teach him to hold the ones who think the same [way] in higher esteem than the others who think differently.</sub>

---

<sup>1</sup>) Notice that "die" is NOT an article here, although it looks like and is inflected like one.

Answer (score 0):

*Der*, *die*, *das* are multi-purpose words in German that occur in quite a number of flavors which can confuse non-native speakers:

1. A simple article. It helps clarifying the Genus of a noun as well as its   state of individualism (because they are *definite* articles, they denounce a definitive item).
2. A demonstrative pronoun, translating to *this* in English - Pronouns don't stand *with* the noun like articles, but rather *for* the noun and are demonstrative as in pointing at something.
3. A relative pronoun, translating to *which* or *that* in English - Here they stand for a noun typically found in the main clause

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, die(**DP**), die(**RP**) gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als die(**DP**), die(**RP**) anders denken.

A sure way to identify a demonstrative pronoun as in your example sentence is: if you can replace "die" with "diejenigen" without changing the meaning, it surely is a DP.

> Der sicherste Weg, einen jungen Menschen zu korrumpieren, ist, ihn zu lehren, *diejenigen*, die gleich denken, höher einzuschätzen als *diejenigen*, die anders denken.

A demonstrative pronoun doesn't necessarily need to refer to something (while a relative pronoun needs to). In your example, the DP doesn't. It's like pointing into a specific direction and saying "this one". So, the DP *die* do not reference a noun, while the RP *die* reference the DP.

A proper translation would be

> The safest way to corrupt the youth is to teach them to value the ones that think alike higher than the ones that think different.